# Understanding eclipse project natures and workflow for web development

Tags: javascript, django, eclipse, workflow

I need to code some complicated web page with new html5 features, using javascript a lot. Later I will use this as a template for Django.
I was advised to use Eclipse for JavaScript Web Developers, and to create a project «with Javascript nature». Okay, I could do the entire client side development in this project.
The question is: when it comes to server coding, should I just create Django project and copy template files there, or rather change something in the project «nature» (or how you call it) to make project handle both javascript and Python editing features? Or probably, there are another good ways to organise the work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Eclipse all the time for Django development of both front-end and back-end code.  I usually create the project with the "django project nature" using the Aptana PyDev plugin (typically after importing my code, I'll right click on the django project directory and choose from the menu "PyDev > Set as Django Project".)  I don't know your specific situation, but I've never had to explicitly set anything to get javascript files to work.  Typically clicking on a file with a .js extension will open a javascript editor and give me javascript syntax highlighting and such.  If you have the PyDev plugin installed, perhaps you can just click the "Set as Django Project" menu item mentioned above.  I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question properly, but Eclipse does allow you to edit your javascript and Django code fairly well within it's interface.  Hope that helps,

Joe